# Google services project reference

Tags: android, google-play-services

When referencing "google-play-services" project to my android app project my Eclipse gives me a "Java heap space exception".

I was wondering is it enough to add the google play services jar to my project so i can use its functionalit?

Comment: You need to add the "google-play-services_lib" project as a library project. You will find it in your_sdk_root_path/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

Answer (score 0):

You should also include Android library project

Answer (score 0):

The `google-play-services` import is very large so its usually recommended you only import the parts you actual need.

If you go to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup you can find smaller individual apis within the larger `google-play-services` api.

Here are some examples:

> Google Account Login: 
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0
>
> Google Analytics:  com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0
>
> Google Maps:  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0
>
> Google Mobile Ads: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0
>
> Google Play Game services:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.8.0
>
> Android Wear:  com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.0

This site also explains why you should avoid importing the whole api:
http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split